# Having trouble with a beginner dom manipulation exercise while using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Dom Manipulation intro</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="domManStyle.css"> -->

   </head>
   <body>

        <button id="press">Click me</button>
        <p>No one has clicked me</p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="DomManip.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>

//JS
var button = document.getElementById("#press");
var paragraph = document.querySelector("p");



button.addEventListener("press", onClick);



function onClick(){
    paragraph.textContent="Someone Clicked me.";
}
```

This is the first Dom Manipulation exercise I am trying and keep getting an error: Cannot read property addEventListener of null. I have also tried to set up the JS .addEventListener like:

```
 button.addEventListener("press" , function(){
        paragraph.textContent="Someone Clicked me.";
    });
```

but still get the same error.

Comment: you should have a look [Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in your `getElementById` method. You have to call it without *#* as it is already an id and so the id-identifier is not needed:

```
var button = document.getElementById("press");
```

Second, there is no *press* event, you want to listen to a click:

```
button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```